# Transfer 2 drive raid0 / lvm2 system to new drive pair

Tags: grub2, hard-disk, lvm, mdadm, migration

I have a multi-boot, multi-drive system that I want to transfer onto 2 bigger drives.

Currently pc has 2x1TB drives with Fedora 19 running, using RAID0 drive mirroring, with LVM2 on top of the md.  I want to transfer the entire md/lvm set of filesystems to a new pair of 2TB drives configured in the same raid0/lvm2 arrangement.  In addition to Fedora, there are Windows 7 partitions, and other misc partitions to copy.

To make matters harder, the Fedora root filesystem exists in the md/lvm2 partition, so I need to bring up all this infrastructure.  /boot is in a real primary partition.

So I'm able to install the 2 new drives at the same time the old drives are still installed, so it is basically a big copy task, but the details are the tricky part.

Using a GParted Live boot disk, I can go in and configure the new drives in a new raid0 and lvm2 vg called "pool2".  The original vg is called "pool".  I partition & mount up the new filesystems and tar/copy all the files from old to new.  But now the two hard parts are biting me.

1. Getting grub2 to install/boot the new copy of the Fedora partition.
2. Getting Windows to boot on its new copy.

Actually never to go trying #2, 
so for #1, Here's details of what I tried, and where I got stuck.

After the copy, I disconnect the old drives and change new drives to sda and sdb.  Booting back again with the boot iso, Then I have to manually start the raid0 with the commands:

```
mdadm -E --scan
mdadm -A /dev/md0
```

No errors, /proc/mdstat shows the raid active with RAID0.

Then I have to manually start the vg with:

```
vgchange -a y pool2
```

Now to reinstall grub2 on the new partitions:

```
mount /dev/mapper/pool2-root /mnt/fedora
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/fedora/boot

cd /mnt/fedora
mount -o bind /dev dev
mount -o bind /proc proc
mount -o bind /sys sys
mount -t tmpfs tmpfs tmp
chroot /mnt/fedora
grub2-install /dev/sda
```

Everything appears to go fine.  But when I try to reboot from the new disk drives, I either get nothing as if grub2 isn't found, or I get the grub menu and it then fails during the boot very early, because it can't find the root filesystem.

What I think is happening is all the grub.cfg file is still full of the old references such as:

```
root=/dev/mapper/pool-root
rd.lvm.lv=pool/root
and probably UUIDs wrong.
```

(remember the new drives are on pool2).  I also suspect maybe the initrd settings are incorrect for the new locations.

Manually changing these values in grub.cfg don't seem to help, so how can I get this working?  I think I'm really close, but having to do a lot of manual md/lvm2/grub2 commands I'm no expert in, and am missing something.

Comment: Using labels is more robust than UUIDs. On Debian I'd tell you to run `update-grub`, but I'm not sure if Fedora uses the same mechanism. You can run `grub-mkconfig` to generate a new `grub.cfg`.

Answer (score 1):

First, raid0 is striping, mirroring is raid1.  With raid0 if one drive fails you loose everything.

You don't want to make a new volume group.  You want to partition the new disks leaving room for /boot and a partition for the raid, then use `mdadm --create` to create a new raid out of partitions on the new disks.  Then you use `pvcreate` to initialize the new raid array for use with lvm, and `vgextend` to add the new raid array to the existing volume group, and `pvmove` to migrate everything off of the old array, and then use `vgreduce` to remove the old array from the volume group.  Finally, you will want to copy your /boot partition to the new disks and reinstall grub on them with `grub-install`.